# CodeIgniter Eloquent Model Relationship Class Model Not Found

Tags: php, codeigniter, model, eloquent, relational-database

i'm trying to implement eloquent into my CodeIgniter project.

It works good when i call a model in my project (it give me data from my database). But when i'm trying to call relation for its model, it's went wrong and show this message:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Class 'application\models\Profile' not found

Filename: /var/www/public/chupspace-git/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php

Line Number: 750

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/public/chupspace-git/application/models/User.php
Line: 12
Function: hasOne

File: /var/www/public/chupspace-git/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php
Line: 2638
Function: profile

File: /var/www/public/chupspace-git/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php
Line: 2573
Function: getRelationshipFromMethod

File: /var/www/public/chupspace-git/vendor/illuminate/database/Eloquent/Model.php
Line: 3263
Function: getAttribute

File: /var/www/public/chupspace-git/application/controllers/UserController.php
Line: 53
Function: __get

File: /var/www/public/chupspace-git/index.php
Line: 357
Function: require_once
```

I use `"illuminate/database": "5.0.28",` library in my `composer.json`

Here is my model

`User.php`

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = "users";

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('application\models\Profile');
    }
}
```

`Profile.php`

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Profile extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = "user_profiles";
}
```

And here is my directory map.

[image]

Let me know if there is missing of information, so i can update this thread. 
Your help is very valuable to me. Thanks.

Comment: just out of curiosity... why (besides the standard IT response "because I can") go through all the hoops of making Eloquent (an ORM/ActiveRecord implementation that is part of Laravel, an entirely different PHP framework) when CodeIgniter has its own ActiveRecord implementation built-in and working out of the box? just wondering....

Comment: @Javier one of the most troublemaking things in Codeigniter is the missing part how to structure related data through connections - Eloquent is able to define relations - CI's QueryBuilder isn't. I posted a thread related to this topic a couple weeks ago https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-71733.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. We just need to change

`$this->hasOne('application\models\Profile');`

to be

`$this->hasOne(new Profile());`

Here is my full code.

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = "users";

    public function profile()
    {
        // dd();
        return $this->hasOne(new Profile());
    }
}
```

It works good for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load all relation class before use it.

First of all you need to enable in the `application/config/config.php` the composer autoload. Just set `$config['composer_autoload']` to `TRUE`

Then you need to extend your `composer.json` to load every models:

```
{
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ["application/models/"]
}
```

}

Then you need to regenerate the autoload file (run in cli):

```
composer dump-autoload
```

It should be works. There is more other ways to do it, but i think it's the clearest.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I have done this part before, but the error still the same.

Comment: Thanks bro. I forget composer dump-autoload after creating new model class.